# Convert HTML tags and display as styled text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm looking to design a form that will accept HTML tags and convert them into styled text displayed in a separate text area. Think a very simple JSbin. I thought that this would work:

```
 document.getElementById('tagName').innerHTML='variable'
```

But this displays the text along with the tags - I just want the tag.

I need some helpful hints or a nudge in the direction I should go. Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById('tagName').innerHTML=variable`?

Comment: But this displays the text along with the tags.????  Clarify or this question will be closed as an unclear question.

Comment: Post more details in order to understand your problem.

Comment: Here's the Codepen for my project. It might give you a better idea of what I'm doing.

https://codepen.io/jhunnicutt/full/NOyZMq

The first box will take actual html code and the button will render it into converted html. I'd like to type "<h1>My Site</h1>" in one box and then have it displayed as a proper heading in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `contenteditable` attr.

You can use that attribute in order to make editable a DOM element like `div`, `span`, `p`, and so on.

For more info go to [Making content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

On the order hand, to be able to write HTML from a `textarea` and the entered HTML text be rendered into the `contenteditable` element, you need to bind some kind of event in order to get the wrote HTML and then set it into the target `contenteditable` element.

```js
var variable = '<b>EleFromStack</b>',
    tagName = document.getElementById('tagName'),
    textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    
textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  tagName.innerHTML = this.value;  
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed #000
}
```

```html
<textarea id='textarea'>
</textarea>

<div id='tagName' contenteditable='true'>
</div>
```

Comment: contenteditable is good, but it only gets half the problem. I would like to type in tags and then have them rendered as styled text.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://gomakethings.com/two-ways-to-get-and-set-html-content-with-vanilla-javascript/ you want to use `.textContent` to get the text without the tags.

```js
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=document.getElementById('html-elements').textContent
```

```html
<div id="html-elements">
<button>hello</button> <strong><em>world</em></strong>
</div>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is create an input then listen to the value changes and display the inner html in another div

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="input"></input>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Then listen to the change and update the output

```
//JS
const input = document.querySelector('#input'),
      output = document.querySelector('#output');
button.addEventListener('change', () => {
  output.innerHTML = input.value;
})
```

(JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/genokox/edit?html,js,console,output[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/genokox/edit?html,js,console,output))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to write HTML into a text area. The text area is reserved, by the browser engine, to post plain text. Instead of writing out your content to a textarea write it to a DIV or some other content block designed to contain HTML.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this was the crux of my issue, injecting content into the wrong kind of element.